# How to invalidate a JWT token PHP

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I'm trying to invalidate (or remove) a token from `JWT` but I can't achieve that. First I did something like this answer says [Logout issue with Laravel JWT-auth authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29631441/3701102):

```
JWTAuth::invalidate(JWTAuth::getToken())):
```

But I get this error:

> Non-static method Tymon\JWTAuth\JWT::invalidate() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Then I did something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    protected $jwt;

    public function __construct(JWTAuth $jwt)
    {
        $this->jwt = $jwt;
    }

    public function invalidateToken(Request $request)
    {
        $this->jwt->parseToken()->invalidate();

        return response()->json(array('message' => 'log out'));
    }

    ...
}
```

But I can still use the token for another request and I can't remove or invalidate it.

What am I doing wrong to invalidate the token?

**Edit:**

I read another questions from here and issues post from the repo of JWT on [github (this is the library I'm using)](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) and I followed all the examples to invalidate or remove the token and I can't still remove or invalidate it .

Comment: By it's nature you can not invalidate token. Here your options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978658/invalidating-json-web-tokens

Comment: @E_p I'm using this library: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth, I'm not using the library for `nodejs`

Comment: Makes no difference JWT works same for any server side language. There is no mechanism to expire token An accepted answer in link I provided tells you how to deal with it.

Comment: @E_p you are right, thank you !!

Comment: The is an interesting POV about JWT revocation: https://www.dinochiesa.net/?p=1388

Comment: Sorry for opening this 10 months since last activity, but I have also run into the same problem as author. By invalidate, I understand that the author of the library stores the token in some kind of blacklist table and checks the table on every access. However, I am unable to get the invalidate method to work for this library. @pableiros did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @NiCk.JaY I never found a solution. I was wasting a lot of time looking for a solution but I ended up removing the token stored on the client when the user log out

Comment: @pableiros Thanks. After a lot of searching, I found out it was a cache_driver issue. I've posted an answer here explaining it.

Answer (score 1):

The blacklist feature works if cache_driver in your .env file is set to something other than array.

Changing it to file worked for me. However, in my particular case, I was using Entrust too, which causes issues when cache_driver is set to file or database. So, had to drop the blacklist/invalidate functionality.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i think it should look like: `$this->jwt->setToken($old_token)->invalidate(true);`

Answer (score -3):

```
JWTAuth::invalidate(old token);
```