# How do I remove or delete all user JWT token

Tags: php, laravel, api, jwt

How do I remove or delete a JWT token of all users?
I tried to delete the cache folder from `/storage/framework/cache/data`. but no luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to invalidate a JWT token PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38641585/how-to-invalidate-a-jwt-token-php)

Comment: No, i want to log out all logged in user by mannually

Comment: Are you using a specific laravel package on top of Laravel for generating the JWT tokens. Like `tymondesigns/jwt-auth` or `laravel/passport` ?

Comment: Yes, I m using JWT package